# How can I concatinate my csv files in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I just started recently to work with python and pandas, so I am a real noob, but I really want to learn how to handle my problem. However I managed to merge some csv files from a certain path, but I am a little stuck. After merging my csv files, a new file is created that contains all data, but in this case the data is supposed to be displayed in different columns. At the moment each csv file is stored in the column 'a' , but every single file should be stored in a single column within the new created file. Iam thankful for every idea.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv

path = r'C:\Users\....'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")


d = {'col1': [1], 'col2': [3]}
bigdata = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

li = []



for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=False)

bigdata = pd.concat(li, ignore_index=True, axis=1)

bigdata.to_csv('newfile.csv',index=None, header=None)
```

Comment: Have you changed the axis to 0 to see if it gives what you want? `pd.concat(li, axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? `pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it out, but unfortunately the files are merged vertically, but I need to merge them horizontally

Comment: Do all the csv's have the same number of columns with the same column names? I assume they are in that case if you want to combine them vertically then your code `pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` should work. If the column names and/or the number of columns are different then the solution i posted should work. What are you getting?

Comment: Thanks again. All csv's have the same number of culumns and even the same column name. Maybe I should mention that all csv's consist of one column.

Comment: Ok, now what do you get when you do `pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` ? What would you like to get if the answer using the above is not what you want.

Comment: By using `pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` all csv files are merged horizontally together in column 'A' of my new file. My goal is to store each csv file in an own column within the new csv file. In summary file 1 should be stored in column A, file 2 should be stored in column B, etc.

Comment: Did this help?`pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that all your CSV files are Nx1 frames (N rows and 1 column). So, say you have M files, you want to end up with a NxM frame. Is this what you want?

If that's the case, you could try this:

```
files = glob.glob('your_path_to_your_files/*.csv')

# Load the first file of the folder as a starting point
df = pd.read_csv(files[0],delimiter=';')

# Iterate through the folder
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter=';')
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data,df], axis='columns')

all_data.to_csv('all_data.csv',index=False)
```

On the other hand, if your CSV files are Nx2 (N rows and 2 colums) and you want to generate a Mx2 (M=all the rows of all your CSV files), try this:

```
files = glob.glob('your_path_to_your_files/*.csv')

# Load the first file of the folder as a starting point
df = pd.read_csv(files[0],delimiter=';')

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter=';')
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data,df])

# Save this new data frame
all_data.to_csv('all_data.csv',index=False)
```

If this doesn't help, you could edit the question and explain what your data looks like. Also make sure to use the correct delimiter (in my case ";") for your data.

Comment: First of all thank you. I tried your first option, but unfortunately all CSV's from my path are stored in column A of my new created file. As I mentioned below my goal is to store each csv file in an own column within the new csv file. In summary file 1 should be stored in column A, file 2 should be stored in column B, etc.

Comment: Interesting. I've just tried my code and it works. I created 3 separate CSV files, each with a single column with a different name (Column A, Column, B and Column C). The first piece of code I wrote succesfully merges all the files into a single DataFrame.  Even with different column length (I made each CSV have different number of rows), although the missing values are filled with NaN.